# Excel Multiple Cells Included in an IF Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hi im trying to make a IF statement using a whole column so that any rainfall data that is entered that is less than 0 is an error and if it is above it is ok

eg:

rainfall
0

0

1.2

3

data checking

rainfall **ok**

i want it so that any data edited in that column that is less than 0 comes up as an error and if it is greater than 0 it comes up as ok

if that's unclear then I want to make an IF statement that when you change the data in any cell between C2 and C25 if the number you put in is above 0 then where it says data checking/rainfall it says ok and if you put in a number that is below 0 then where it says data checking/rainfall then it says error

I have tried =IF(AND(C2<0,C3<0,C4<0),"error","ok")

all help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you clarify "less than 0"? Do you mean if a negative number is input; i.e.`-0.2`? In other words, no negative numbers are allowed in the column.

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. yes, i want it so that if any negative number  is input where it says data checking/rainfall it says ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need `MIN()`

`=IF(MIN(A:A)<0,"error","ok")`